# Why can't I set intial value for CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

I deleted initial code in html source here https://codepen.io/DerkJanS/pen/owVGZb and tried to do it in javascript instead.

I tried

```
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'htmlmixed',
    value: `<section>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>This is just a HTML example</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  });
```

and

```
  CodeMirror.setValue(`
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>This is just a HTML example</p>
    </div>
  </section>`);
```

but none works: content is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a CodeMirror document:

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true
});

const Doc = CodeMirror.Doc('', 'htmlmixed');

editor.swapDoc(Doc);

Doc.setValue(`
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>This is just a HTML example</p>
    </div>
  </section>`);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/codemirror.min.css"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.65.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks I looked at swapDoc https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html#swapDoc but still don't understand why you need to use it ?

Comment: @user310291 If you are asking about your original snippet, then you are right, it doesn't have much sense as there you just had to fix a typo: `CodeMirror.setValue` to `editor.setValue`. But generally, using docs is a more versatile solution as you can have multiple docs formatted with different mime types, moreover those docs will keep their own state like caret position, that's why I used it in my answer.